# R within() order of operation and logic

Tags: r, logic

I am trying to understand how the within() function in R "works."  For example, in the code below I try to make a new variable named "FEELS" based on a condition.  The first two uses of the within() function do not work.  The third use of the within() function works, but I am not confident I understand the logic of "why" it works.  Any help is appreciated.

```
DF <- data.frame(DATE = seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2015-12-31"), "month"), TEMP = c(30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 90, 80, 70, 60))

DF <- within(DF, {
  FEELS[30 <= TEMP & TEMP <=  50] <- "Cold"
  FEELS[60 <= TEMP & TEMP <=  70] <- "Good"
  FEELS[80 <= TEMP & TEMP <= 100] <- "Hot"
})

DF <- within(DF, {
  FEELS                           <- "Cold"
  FEELS[60 <= TEMP & TEMP <=  70] <- "Good"
  FEELS[80 <= TEMP & TEMP <= 100] <- "Hot"
})

DF

DF <- within(DF, {
  FEELS                           <- NA
  FEELS[60 <= TEMP & TEMP <=  70] <- "Good"
  FEELS[80 <= TEMP & TEMP <= 100] <- "Hot"
  FEELS[is.na(FEELS)]             <- "Cold"
})

DF
```

Comment: Try putting a call to `browser` before all those lines. That should make things clearer.

Comment: ...an extra hint: pay attention to the lengths of the objects you see once you're in the `browser`, and what effect this has on subsetting operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's break these down one by one.

**1.** This one simply results in an error message:

`Error in FEELS[30 <= TEMP & TEMP <= 50] <- "Cold" :    object 'FEELS' not found`

That makes perfect sense. You haven't yet defined `FEELS`, so subsetting it results in an error.

**2.** This one's interesting and can be seen more clearly if you do it outside of 'within'

```
FEELS <- "cold"
tf <- 60 <= DF$TEMP & DF$TEMP <=  70
tf

[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

FEELS[tf] <- "Good"
FEELS

 [1] "cold" NA     NA     "Good" "Good" NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     "Good"
[12] "Good"
```

R starts with a vector of length one containing "cold", but your subsetting forces it to extend and place "Good" in all elements where it's `TRUE`. R doesn't have any values for everything that's `FALSE`, so puts NA there.

**3.** The last one is pretty straightforward. You start with an NA vector which is extended in the same way as the one in 2. You then replace all the NAs which are left with "cold".

Comment: Nice illustration that `within` is just a distractor here.

Comment: @Gregor I'm not sure it is a distractor, entirely. Based on recycling in `within(data.frame(A=1:6), {B=1})`, one might think that `B` is the full vector as soon as it's created inside `{...}`.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent response.  Just wondering if the last approach is the "best" way to create my conditional variable (other than a nested ifelse).

Comment: @user1491868 Not sure what sebastian would say, but I'd suggest having a look at `cut`, which seems well suited.

Comment: @Frank sebastian would most certainly say that.

Answer (score 4):

When you create an object inside `within(DF, {...})`, it does not automatically have the same length as columns of `DF`. Instead, it will be "recycled" at the end of `{...}` to fill out the column

```
within(data.frame(A=1:6), { B = 1; C = 1:2 })
#   A C B
# 1 1 1 1
# 2 2 2 1
# 3 3 1 1
# 4 4 2 1
# 5 5 1 1
# 6 6 2 1
```

If, before the end of `{...}`, you want to modify an object as if it were a full column, it must have the correct length:

```
within(data.frame(A=1:6), {
  D = 1 
  D[ A < 3 ] = 0
  D2 = rep(1, length(A))
  D2[A < 3 ] = 0
})

#   A D2  D
# 1 1  0  0
# 2 2  0  0
# 3 3  1 NA
# 4 4  1 NA
# 5 5  1 NA
# 6 6  1 NA
```

To understand why `D2` gave the expected output while `D` did not, try examining the objects in steps, using `browser()` as suggested by @sebastian-c or following the steps as illustrated in his answer.

In the OP's case, initializing with `rep` and then making several substitutions is one option. Another would be to use `cut`, which is designed for assigning labels to intervals of ordered data.